# Determining ManyToMany vs OneToMany using ClassMetadata

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I am using ClassMetadata to determine the structure of a hibernate POJO.

I need to determine if a collection is OneToMany or ManyToMany.  Where is this information?  Can I get to it without using reflection?  See my code below.

```
//Get the class' metadata
ClassMetadata cmd=sf.getClassMetadata(o.getClass());

for(String propertyName:cmd.getPropertyNames()){
    if (cmd.getPropertyType(propertyName).isCollectionType() && cmd.??()) //Do something with @ManyToMany collections.
}
```

All I need is method to tell me if it's a ManyTo____ relationship.  I see getPropertyLaziness(), but that doesn't always guarantee the type of collection.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that simple, unfortunatelly. Your best bet to detect this is by checking for particular `CollectionPersister` implementation:

```
SessionFactory sf = ...;

// Get the class' metadata
ClassMetadata cmd = sf.getClassMetadata(o.getClass());

for(String propertyName:cmd.getPropertyNames()) {
  Type propertyType = cmd.getPropertyType(propertyName);
  if (propertyType.isCollectionType()) {
    CollectionType collType = (CollectionType) propertyType;

    // obtain collection persister
    CollectionPersister persister = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sf)
      .getCollectionPersister(collType.getRole());

    if (persister instanceof OneToManyPersister) {
      // this is one-to-many
    } else {
     // this is many-to-many OR collection of elements
    }
  } // if
} // for
```

Comment: Oh wait.  I think I found it.  EntityType.isOneToOne().  However, I couldn't have found this without you.  I really appreciate all your help!  Your entries help me and hopefully others.  Good work!

Comment: I think I spoke too soon.  EntityType.isOneToOne() is always false for some reason.  I didn't find a OneToOnePersister.  Any ideas?

Comment: `EntityType.isOneToOne()` is the way to go. Or you can check for property type to be `instanceof OneToOneType` which is the same thing.  You'll NEVER have one-to-one as part of collection, though - you're checking some other property, right?

Comment: They are first checked with isEntityType().  Then cast to EntityType.  Always false.  It almost looks it from a site that (probably) shows the source code:  http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/hibernate/type/ManyToOneType.html.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, the debugger shows the @OneToOne entity as a ManyToOne.  They must have reused the same class for both @OneToOne and @ManyToOne.  Do you see this as well?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get your response. Are you saying that you're testing a property that **is** mapped as one-to-one (and thus is not part of collection) but isOneToOne() returns false? If that's the case what concrete implementation of EntityType is returned?

Comment: I'm going to make a new issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381862/onetoone-getting-returned-as-manytoonetype.  The comments don't have enough room.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility.

Direct Known Subclasses: ManyToOneType, OneToOneType.

```
       SessionFactory sf = ...;

       ClassMetadata cmd = sf.getClassMetadata(o.getClass());

       for (String propertyName : cmd.getPropertyNames()) {
            Type propertyType = cmd.getPropertyType(propertyName);

            if (propertyType.isEntityType()) {
                EntityType entityType = (EntityType) propertyType;

                if (entityType instanceof ManyToOneType) {
                    System.out.println("this is ManyToOne");
                } else if (entityType instanceof OneToOneType) {
                    System.out.println("this is OneToOne");
                }
            }
        }
```