# How to get Hibernate object relations dynamically?

Tags: java, hibernate, database-relations

I'm using Hibernate and I need to find a way of retrieving the relations for an object dynamically at run-time. I can't find this in the API.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "relations for an object dynamically"? criteria API ?

Comment: e.g. given a Person object that I could find out that there is a one-to-many relationship to PhoneNumber, and a one-to-one relationship to HomeTown

Comment: I guess the following thread answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374748/determining-manytomany-vs-onetomany-using-classmetadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best recommendation is to use plain JDBC [DatabaseMetaData](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

DatabaseMetaData.getCrossReference

DatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys

DatabaseMetaData.getExportedKeys

[Examples](http://books.google.de/books?id=a8W8fKQYiogC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=jdbc+metadata+foreign+keys&source=bl&ots=oi3KyF8ZEQ&sig=7Tb-BIkRLLqg0ZYPoCgDishwvi8&hl=de&ei=7ajyS7rmH4OCmgO60dCvDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=jdbc%20metadata%20foreign%20keys&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

What You look for is SessionFactory's getClassMetadata() method. It returns ClassMetadata object describing given entity.

Comment: great thanks. but which methods do i need to call on the ClassMetadata object?